# Delete ALL MySQL Database entries via Cronjob

Tags: mysql, cron

I'm dumbing my Databases via Cronjob. Now I want to delete the whole content of a db before I restore the Backup.

I tried to add "--add-drop-database" to my dumb command but it changed nothing.
I although can't add "--add-drop-table" because in the db where i want to restore my backup are more tables than in the backup file.

did someone know a solution?

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `DROP DATABASE databasename;` before import.

Comment: this works - but deletes the whole database, i just want to delete the content of the database. But I've added CREATE DATABASE directly after it and so it works fine :) thx!

Comment: yep, just like in a regular routine, where you drop a table and re-create it right after :)